# curl: (52) Empty reply from server while calling ejabbered API Commands

Tags: docker, ejabberd

My ejabberd server is running in a docker container and I am trying to call ejabberd API commands. Somehow I am always getting "curl: (52) Empty reply from server". I don't know where I am wrong in configuring yml file for ejabbered.
I tried getting the list of vhosts and registered_users. But all I am getting is Empty reply.

Below is my YML file

```
    hosts:
  - localhost

loglevel: 4
log_rotate_size: 10485760
log_rotate_date: ""
log_rotate_count: 1
log_rate_limit: 100

certfiles:
  - /home/ejabberd/conf/server.pem

ca_file: "/home/ejabberd/conf/cacert.pem"

## When using let's encrypt to generate certificates
##certfiles:
##  - /etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/fullchain.pem
##  - /etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/privkey.pem
##
##ca_file: "/etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/fullchain.pem"

listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls_required: true
  -
    port: 5269
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 524288
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: 127.0.0.1
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      /: ejabberd_web_admin
      "/api": mod_http_api
      "/bosh": mod_bosh
      "/captcha": ejabberd_captcha
      "/upload": mod_http_upload
      "/ws": ejabberd_http_ws
      "/oauth": ejabberd_oauth
  -
    port: 5180
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      /: ejabberd_web_admin
  -
    port: 1883
    ip: "::"
    module: mod_mqtt
    backlog: 1000
  ##
  ## https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#stun-and-turn
  ## ejabberd_stun: Handles STUN Binding requests
  ##
  ##-
  ##  port: 3478
  ##  ip: "0.0.0.0"
  ##  transport: udp
  ##  module: ejabberd_stun
  ##  use_turn: true
  ##  turn_ip: "{{ IP }}"
  ##  auth_type: user
  ##  auth_realm: "example.com"
  ##-
  ##  port: 3478
  ##  ip: "0.0.0.0"
  ##  module: ejabberd_stun
  ##  use_turn: true
  ##  turn_ip: "{{ IP }}"
  ##  auth_type: user
  ##  auth_realm: "example.com"
  ##- 
  ##  port: 5349
  ##  ip: "0.0.0.0"
  ##  module: ejabberd_stun
  ##  certfile: "/home/ejabberd/conf/server.pem"
  ##  tls: true
  ##  use_turn: true
  ##  turn_ip: "{{ IP }}"
  ##  auth_type: user
  ##  auth_realm: "example.com"
  ##
  ## https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#sip
  ## To handle SIP (VOIP) requests:
  ##
  ##-
  ##  port: 5060
  ##  ip: "0.0.0.0"
  ##  transport: udp
  ##  module: ejabberd_sip
  ##-
  ##  port: 5060
  ##  ip: "0.0.0.0"
  ##  module: ejabberd_sip
  ##-
  ##  port: 5061
  ##  ip: "0.0.0.0"
  ##  module: ejabberd_sip
  ##  tls: true

s2s_use_starttls: optional

acl:
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - 127.0.0.0/8
      - ::1/128
      - ::FFFF:127.0.0.1/128
  admin:
    user:
      - "admin@localhost"

access_rules:
  local:
    allow: local
  c2s:
    deny: blocked
    allow: all
  announce:
    allow: admin
  configure:
    allow: admin
  muc_create:
    allow: local
  pubsub_createnode:
    allow: local
  trusted_network:
    allow: loopback

api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
      - mod_http_api
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who:
      access:
        allow:
          ##acl: loopback
          acl: admin
      oauth:
        scope: "ejabberd:admin"
        scope: "registered_users"
        access:
          allow:
            ##acl: loopback
            acl: admin
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "public commands":
    from:
      - mod_http_api
    who:
      ip: 127.0.0.1/8
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
      

shaper:
  normal: 1000
  fast: 50000

shaper_rules:
  max_user_sessions: 10
  max_user_offline_messages:
    5000: admin
    100: all
  c2s_shaper:
    none: admin
    normal: all
  s2s_shaper: fast

max_fsm_queue: 10000

acme:
   contact: "mailto:example-admin@example.com"
   ca_url: "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"

modules:
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce:
    access: announce
  mod_avatar: {}
  mod_blocking: {}
  mod_bosh: {}
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {}
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_fail2ban: {}
  mod_http_api: {}
  mod_http_upload:
    put_url: https://@HOST@:5443/upload
  mod_last: {}
  mod_mam:
    ## Mnesia is limited to 2GB, better to use an SQL backend
    ## For small servers SQLite is a good fit and is very easy
    ## to configure. Uncomment this when you have SQL configured:
    ## db_type: sql
    assume_mam_usage: true
    default: never
  mod_mqtt: {}
  mod_muc:
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    access_mam:
      - allow
    default_room_options:
      allow_subscription: true  # enable MucSub
      mam: false
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  mod_proxy65:
    access: local
    max_connections: 5
  mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    plugins:
      - flat
      - pep
    force_node_config:
      ## Avoid buggy clients to make their bookmarks public
      storage:bookmarks:
        access_model: whitelist
  mod_push: {}
  mod_push_keepalive: {}
  mod_register:
    ## Only accept registration requests from the "trusted"
    ## network (see access_rules section above).
    ## Think twice before enabling registration from any
    ## address. See the Jabber SPAM Manifesto for details:
    ## https://github.com/ge0rg/jabber-spam-fighting-manifesto
    ip_access: trusted_network
  mod_roster:
    versioning: true
  mod_sip: {}
  mod_s2s_dialback: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_stream_mgmt:
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  mod_vcard: {}
  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}
  mod_version:
    show_os: false

### Local Variables:
### mode: yaml
### End:
### vim: set filetype=yaml tabstop=8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a configuration that includes at least those parts:

```
hosts:
  - localhost

listen:
    port: 5443
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    request_handlers:
      "/api": mod_http_api
  -
    port: 5280
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/api": mod_http_api

api_permissions:
  "admin access":
    who:
      access:
        allow: all
    what:
      - "registered_users"

modules:
  ...
  mod_http_api: {}
```

All those queries work correctly:

```
curl -X GET \
    http://localhost:5280/api/registered_users?host=localhost

curl -X POST \
    http://localhost:5280/api/registered_users \
    -d '{"host": "localhost"}'

curl -X GET \
    --insecure \
    https://localhost:5443/api/registered_users?host=localhost

curl -X POST \
    --insecure \
    https://localhost:5443/api/registered_users \
    -d '{"host": "localhost"}'
```

All them report the same result:

```
["admin"]
```

In the ejabberd log file you should view something like:

```
2022-02-14 20:13:41.686208+00:00 [info] (<0.758.0>) 
  Accepted connection [::ffff:172.18.0.1]:50040 -> [::ffff:172.18.0.2]:5443
2022-02-14 20:13:41.696906+00:00 [info] 
  API call registered_users [{<<"host">>,<<"localhost">>}] from ::ffff:172.18.0.1:50040
```